# Conditional compilation in ASP.Net MVC3 or MVC4 with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

C# Preprocessor
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk(v=vs.100).aspx

Is there any way we can control MVC Views, Controllers, Models with conditional compilation?
This is for different versions of software releases.

Ex: release 1.1
    release 1.2 etc...

I mean some features will not be available in 1 version based on conditional compilation.
This is for not maintaining different branches and merging them together at end.

FYI... I do not find option conditional compilation option in vs 2010, i used to do this with visual basic 6.0.

Comment: Are you meaning #if? : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

Comment: Yes, something like that, the idea is to maintain the app for multiple versions of build instead of going through the pain of merging and integration.

Comment: You likely be much better off by turning features on/off based on some configuration setting rather than writing strange code covered with `#if...` blocks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you *can*:

Models/Controllers:

```
  #if DEBUG
     // your content
  #else
     // your content
  #endif
```

Views (Razor):

```
@{
  #if DEBUG
     // your content
  #else
     // your content
  #endif
}
```

But it doesn't sound like a great way to support versioning... (JMO)

Comment: Yes, after analysis this could be the only answer...!

Answer (score 0):

You need two project files, one for each version, and define the symbols yourself. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205908/what-net-framework-and-c-sharp-version-should-i-target-with-my-class-library#answer-1206049).